# Angular Flex Directives Re Usability

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I am having an angular 4 application which uses angular flex for layouts instead of Bootstrap.

But for alignments in each div tag I have to give:

```
 fxLayout.xs="column"
 fxLayout="row"  
 fxLayoutAlign="start center" 
 fxLayoutGap="18px"
```

Can anyone suggest how to reuse these directives instead of writing it for each tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `host` property from the `@Directive` decorator.

Create a Directive and add those directives to the host property. Example:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[reusable]',
  host: {
    '[hidden]': 'hidden'
  }
})
export class ReusableDirective {

  hidden = true;

}
```

Comment: But, i have many div tags with these attributes in a page, if i use this approach how will it differentiate the tags?

Comment: Ah. I see what you are saying now. You'd apply this directive to all the divs, the same way you'd apply a CSS class. At least this way you only have to write one directive instead of 4 for each div.